# How to pass observableArray to template using data

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I'm trying to pass observableArray to template:

```
<template id="my-template">
    <pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify($data)"></pre>
    <!-- prints: { isWarning: false } --/>
</template>


<div data-bind="template: { name: my-template, data: { errors: myObservableArray, isWarning: false }}"></div>
```

It looks like the observableArray cannot be passed as data. I tried to call it with `()`:

```
template: { 
   name: my-template, 
   data: { errors: myObservableArray(), isWarning: false }
}
```

This prints `{ errors: [], isWarning: false }`.

However I want to pass ObservableArray, not Array to the template.

Is it possible without changing the JS?

Comment: You are passing a name of the template without quotes, might this be a source of the problem? Actually every other thing seems okay, you should be able to pass an observable array like that (without parentheses), and then use it in your template like an observableArray, not simple JS array. Could you also post here what are you getting in the first variant? Are you getting some error in console? If so, please, post it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The observableArray is correctly passed to the template. The reason this isn't printed is because `JSON.stringify` returns undefined for knockout observables, which isn't rendered in the `pre`-element. To make the example work, use `ko.toJSON` instead. Have a look at the snippet below:

```js
ko.applyBindings({ 
  myObservableArray: ko.observableArray(['error 1', 'error 2', 'error 3'])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<template id="my-template">
  <!-- ko foreach: errors -->
  <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></pre>
</template>


<div data-bind="template: { name: 'my-template', data: { errors: myObservableArray, isWarning: false }}"></div>
```

Comment: That is very weird behavior, indeed. Just out of curiosity, do you know why JSON.stringify would return undefined for knockout observables? How is that even possible?

Comment: Good question. My assumption was that knockout implemented a `toJSON` method on the observables, which by [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description) takes responsibility for the serialization, but I could not find that in the knockout source. Don't know why they would return undefined either... returning the result of `ko.toJSON` would have made more sense.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `toJSON` function being called by `JSON.stringify`. Interesting...

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this is a problem with your [binding context](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html). I often find it invaluable to leave the following debugging snippet immediately before the closing `</body>` tag during development, removed/commented out during deployment. This will display the everything knockout "knows" about your app, specifically what was passed into `.applyBindings(...)`. Especially here important is the value hierarchy.

```
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></pre>
```

What you are trying to do is most definitely possible. Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/pimbrouwers/1gp8tjmr/17/) demonstrating this. Take note of the `$data.myObservableArray`. The usage of `$data` here is requesting the value from the current binding context.

As an architectural suggestion, I would recommend favoring [components](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html) over templates, in virtually all cases. They offer greater reusability, asynchronous processing and segmentation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost perfect, I just put template name in '' and passed your array with () to pass evaluated value, It worked.

```js
function VM(){
var self = this;
self.myObservableArray = ko.observableArray(["error1","error2","error3","error4","error4"]);
self.isWarning = ko.observable(false);
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<template id="my-template">
    <pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify($data)"></pre>
</template>


<div data-bind="template: { name: 'my-template', data: { errors: myObservableArray(), isWarning: isWarning() }}"></div>
```

Comment: I don't want to pass my array with (), I need to pass observableArray, because in my real template I have foreach binding and I need it to reflect changes.

Comment: Can you provide actual template bindings you are trying to achieve ? Does it look like       template: { name: 'my-template', foreach: myObservableArray }